# I keep getting an error called "TypeIntializationException was unhandled" and I don't know how

Tags: c#

this is my program.cs file (This is all done on VS 2010 in C#)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace GameLoop
    {
     static class Program
        {
            static FastLoop _fastLoop = new FastLoop(GameLoop);
            /// <summary>
            /// The main entry point for the application.
         /// </summary>
            [STAThread]
         static void Main()
         {
               Application.EnableVisualStyles();
             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
         }
         static void GameLoop(double elapsedTime)
          {
                //GameCode goes here
             //Get Input
             //Process
            //Render
                System.Console.WriteLine("loop");
         }
      }
    }
```

this one is my FastLoop.cs file (This is all done on VS 2010 in C#)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace GameLoop
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Message
        {
            public IntPtr hWnd;
            public Int32 msg;
            public IntPtr wParam;
            public IntPtr lParam;
            public uint time;
            public System.Drawing.Point p;
        }

        public class FastLoop
        {
            [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
            public static extern bool PeekMessage(
                out Message msg,
                IntPtr hWnd,
                uint messageFilterMin,
                uint messageFilterMax,
                uint flags);

            PreciseTimer _timer = new PreciseTimer();
            public delegate void LoopCallback(double elapsedTime);
            LoopCallback _callback;

            public FastLoop(LoopCallback callback)
            {
                _callback = callback;
                Application.Idle += new EventHandler(OnApplicationEnterIdle);
            }
            void OnApplicationEnterIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                while (IsAppStillIdle())
                {
                    _callback(_timer.GetElapsedTime());
                }
            }
            private bool IsAppStillIdle()
            {
                Message msg;
                return !PeekMessage(out msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0);

            }
        }
    }
```

this one is my PerciseTimer.cs file (This is all done on VS 2010 in C#)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace GameLoop
    {
        public class PreciseTimer
        {
            [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [DllImport("kernal32")]
            private static extern bool QueryPerformanceFrequency(ref long PerformanceFrequency);

             [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [DllImport("kernal32")]
        private static extern bool QueryPerformanceCounter(ref long PerformanceCount);

            long _ticksPerSecond = 0;
            long _previousElapsedTime = 0;

            public PreciseTimer()
            {
                QueryPerformanceFrequency(ref _ticksPerSecond);
                GetElapsedTime();//get rid if first rubbish result
            }
            public double GetElapsedTime()
            {
                long time = 0;
                QueryPerformanceCounter (ref time);
                double elapsedTime = (double)(time -_previousElapsedTime)/(double)_ticksPerSecond;

                _previousElapsedTime = time;
                return elapsedTime;
        }
    }
    }
```

this on is my form1.cs file (This is all done on VS 2010 in C#)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace GameLoop
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            bool _fullscreen = true;
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                simpleOpenGlControl1.InitializeContexts();
                if (_fullscreen)
                {
                    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

                }
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void simpleOpenGlControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: I'd move `_fastLoop = new FastLoop(GameLoop);` into the `main` method.

Comment: And why do you use native interop for your timer, instead of `StopWatch`?

Comment: I am ashamed now.. I found the error, I spelled Kernel as "Kernal" so my system couldn't locate the Kernel32.dll file

Comment: Glad to hear you got it figured out. :) I'm closing this question because it was a simple typo and it's already resolved.

Comment: Anna, if you hadn't of closed this I would have answered that a TypeInitializationException is either going to be caused by something in the constructor or something initialized when the class is created.  So commenting (or moving code) out of the constructor to eliminate that possibility is always the first step to debugging this error, and then commenting out member variables to find out which it is would be the next step.  And that, I think, could have been helpful to the next person who happened accross this post.

Comment: @BrandonMoore I'm happily reopening so you can put up your answer. Sounds great to me. :) (Incidentally, I only noticed your comment cause I checked back on the question. In the future, please use "`@Anna`" so that I get notified.)

Comment: @AnnaLear Actually started to on the last comment but it wasn't doing the autocomplete thing so I figured it wouldn't work... of course I prolly shoulda just left it there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A TypeInitializationException happens because your type couldn't be initiazed due to another exception that ocurred either in the constructor or because of statically initialized fields.

- Usually a TypeInitializationException is just a wrapper around another exception that actually caused the problem so checking the inner exception will usually show you the issue.
- If that doesn't work, try commenting (or moving code) out of the constructor to eliminate that possibility.
- Move the initialization of any static fields into functions and call them explicitly.